# Não soma valores

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando somar dois valores, por exemplo:

a = 400;
b = 200;

Tento a soma por meio de "a + b", no entanto ao invés do jQuery me retornar "600" ele me retorna "400200".

O código real é este:

```
var startField = $dialogContent.find("input[name='newdate']").val();
var duracao = $dialogContent.find("input[name='duracao']").val();
console.log('final: ' + startField  + duracao * 60000);
```

O que é preciso para receber a somatória dos valores?

Comment: insere o seu código na pergunta para análise, o jQuery está concatenando os valores e não somando.

Comment: Coloquei o trecho do meu código Filipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja:

```
console.log('final: ' + startField  + duracao * 60000);
```

O sistema irá interpretar da seguinte forma:

1. 'final' é uma string então será concatenada com a variável startField, mesmo que essa seja numérica.
2. O resultado da operação 1. será uma string, então também será concatenado com o resultado da operação duração*60000, uma vez que a multiplicação será resolvida antes da concatenação.

O que você deve fazer é utilizar parênteses para que a operação seja realizada antes da concatenação com a string "final":

```
console.log('final: ' + (startField  + duracao * 60000) );
```

Ou então utilize uma variável para armazenar a operação antes de concatenar:

```
var total = startField  + duracao * 60000;
console.log('final: ' + total );
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode forçar a conversão das suas variáveis para numérico realizando uma soma que não mudasse o resultado da variável, como nos exemplos abaixo:

```
var string = "10"; //retorna uma string
var numero = string - 0; //devido ao cálculo - 0, retorna agora um numerico
```

Em adição a isto, como o JavaScript utiliza o operador `+` tanto para soma de valores, quanto para concatenação de strings, é importante que você separe o escopo da sua soma com parênteses, por exemplo:

```
console.log('final: ' + (startField  + duracao * 60000));
```

Exemplo: **[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/7ppdcbze/)**

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente consegui resolver com o "parseInt".

```
var startField = $dialogContent.find("input[name='newdate']").val();
var duracao = $dialogContent.find("input[name='duracao']").val();
console.log('final: ' + (parseInt(startField) + parseInt(duracao) * 60000));
```